# Why does the metal ball have no appreciable charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, charge, conductors

here is the question:

A hollow conductor is positively charged. A small uncharged metal ball is lowered by a silk thread through a small opening in the top of the conductor and allowed to touch its inner surface. After the ball is removed, it will have:

This question came in the exam and I did not know how to approach it. I chose "no appreciable charge" by guessing and it turned out correct because I know that there is no electric field through a hollow conductor !

Comment: This [classic PSSC film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1kKGeLE1xI) from 1959 gives an answer.

Comment: The charge resides on the outer surface (from Gauss' law). Touching on the inner surface will thus not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Both the hollow sphere and the small metal ball are conductors, i.e. electric charge can move freely around in them. As long as they are separate the air between them acts as an insulator, so the charge stays on the hollow sphere. When the objects touch in principle the charge can move from one object to the other. But does it?

One property of electric charge is that the charge carriers (it does not matter if you model it as a fluid or a bunch of particles) repel each other. This means that they always have the tendency to stay away from each other and disperse as much as possible. In the case of a sphere this is particularly simple: the charge distributes evenly over the outer surface of the sphere. The inner surface, on the other hand, stays free of charge, since it would mean that some charge carriers come closer to others against the repelling force. The situation does not change if you touch with the metal ball on the inside. The charge will not flow to the inside, since this would bring the charges closer together, while they always have the tendency to move away from each other. So the uncharged ball remains uncharged.

If the metal ball would touch the outside, however, some charges have the opportunity to move even farther away from other charges and will flow to the ball until it has accumulated enough charge to balance the "pressure" of the charges on the sphere's surface.

A [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) works according to the same principle.